# How do I update a form from a static class?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

this might be a duplicate, but I'm unable to find exactly what I need.

Here is my problem:

I have a main form, from which I create some sub form with a list vew to do some stuff in.

That's sub form code:

```
public partial class AccessGroupForm : Form
{
    public AccessGroupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Fillitems(PackageGroup[] pack)
    {
        foreach (var assignment in pack) //filling the listview
        {   
            list_view.Items.Add(assignment.Name).SubItems.Add(assignment.Id.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and a static class to load this form:

```
public static class AGView
{
    public static void Load(PackageGroup[] pack)
    {
        access_group = AG;
        AccessGroupForm AGform = new AccessGroupForm();
        AGform.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        AGform.Fillitems(pack);
        AGform.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to have is to be able to update the form via this static class upon pressing the button for example:

```
private void UpdateMeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AGView.UpdateMe()
}
```

How do I access exact same form I created with the `AGView.Load(pack)` method?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Key search terms: "C# tutorial". Static classes can still have static members. That being said, it would probably be cleaner to define an interface between the forms and supply that - instead of relying on an outside moderator / static class.

Comment: I would return the created form from the static method, store it *somewhere* and manage further updates using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty bad practice to use a static class to control a form. Because there is only one "instance" of a static class while a form can have multiple instances.

But if you *really* want to do this, just change the static class to something like this:

```
public static class AGView
{      
    private static AccessGroupForm AGform = new AccessGroupForm(); 
    public static void Load(PackageGroup[] pack)
    {
        access_group = AG;
        AGform.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        AGform.Fillitems(pack);
        AGform.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Now you can just use `AGForm` to access the form.

But keep in mind that this is really bad practice.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's kinda bad, currently it's just a quick workarround. Going to rework it when I got time.

Comment: @Amarula if you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a static instance of your form.

```
public static class AGView
{    
    private static AccessGroupForm AGform;  
    public static void Load(PackageGroup[] pack)
    {
    access_group = AG;
    AGform = new AccessGroupForm();
    AGform.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    AGform.Fillitems(pack);
    AGform.ShowDialog();

    }
    public static void UpdateMe()
    {
        if(AGform != null)
        {  
            AGform.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it then like this:

```
private void UpdateMeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AGView.UpdateMe()
}
```

Just be sure to dispose your form when you no longer need it! Otherwise it will be allocated for as long as the program is running because it is a static.

Maybe use a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) class instead of a static class?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Going to try singleton.